# "URL pattern to include" not working in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Tried to capture request having only specific url e.g "www.yahoo.com" in URL but JMeter capturing all the requests from google, mozilla etc

Tried with patterm :

```
.*www.yahoo.com.*
```

But not working.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce described behaviour using latest [JMeter 5.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-5.1/)

[image]

According to the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

> **Patterns to Include** Regular expressions that are matched against the full URL that is sampled. Allows filtering of requests that are recorded. **All requests pass through**, but only those that meet the requirements of the Include/Exclude fields are recorded. If both Include and Exclude are left empty, then everything is recorded (which can result in dozens of samples recorded for each page, as images, stylesheets, etc. are recorded).

It means that you will see all the requests in the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, but only those which match your regular expression will be stored under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

Also be aware that `www.yahoo.com` and `yahoo.com` are different servers, you might want to reconsider your test scenario.

Check out [JMeter Proxy Step by Step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) guide for more information on recording in JMeter